# GitKraken Registration

Tags: git, gitkraken

I've been using GitEye for about a year, now.

I saw a review on the GitKraken client and decided to try it.  It seems like it's a feature-rich client.

However, it pops a small message requiring registration within 5 days.  It offers a link for them to send an email to me.  However, I have tried several times to use this link, but I haven't received an email from them to be able to register the product.

I located their Facebook page and sent them a message there asking how to resolve this.  I see no 'Support' link on their web site.

Has anyone else experienced this ?  If so, how was it resolved ?

Thanks for anyone's insights.

Comment: Check your spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here must involve Hotmail.  I changed the registration email to my Gmail account and received the registration email almost immediately.